# Why does sympy override `__new__` instead of `__init__`?

Tags: python

Every object in [`sympy`](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) is a subclass of the [Basic](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/basic.py) class, and they all use `__new__` without `__init__`, and mostly it's something like

```
def __new__(cls, some, parameter, **others):
    obj = parentclass.__new__(cls, **others)
    obj.some = some
    obj.parameter = parameter
    return obj
```

What's the difference to using `__init__` like

```
def __init__(self, some, parameter, **others):
    parentclass.__init__(self, **others)  # or super().__init__(...)
    self.some = some
    self.parameter = parameter
```

?

Comment: I guess they are all supposed to be immutable?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I believe they need to be hashable to avoid re-doing work that's already been done a.la memoization.

Comment: It might just be a historical accident; older versions (e.g. 0.5.x) have a significantly more complex structure where maybe it was justified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Number](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/numbers.py#L210)  . They want the class of the object to be flexible. `Number(...) => Int/Float/...` which can not be achieved by `__init__`.

Furthermore the `__init__` would get the arguments of `__new__` but you do not need the original arguments, see [matexpr.py](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/matrices/expressions/matexpr.py#L299) or you need them to be adapted to what `__new__` already did (for example [for `__reduce__`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/basic.py#L93)).

Most object define their own `__slots__` so there are fixed attributes that can be assigned to them. Assignment can be done in `__new__` and `__init__`. I do not see the need to open a new `__init__` for just setting them and doing no other operations - As Martijn Pieters and user4815162342 [[source]](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__) pointed out the objects are immutable.

Sometimes `__init__` is called not, once or twice if you change the class:

```
class X(object):
    def __new__(self): # sorry but self is the class I apologize!
        obj = object.__new__(Y)
        return obj
    def __init__(self):
        print 1

>>> class Y(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 2
>>> X() # no __init__ call, limiting you to stay in the class hierarchy
<__main__.Y object at 0x7f287e769350>
>>> class Y(X):
    def __init__(self):
        print 2


>>> X() # one __init__ call
2
<__main__.Y object at 0x7f287e7693d0>
>>> class X(object):
    def __new__(self):
        obj = Y()
        return obj
    def __init__(self):
        print 1


>>> class Y(X):
    def __new__(self):
        return object.__new__(self)
    def __init__(self):
        print 2


>>> X() # __init__ called twice, structure copied from number.py
2
2
<__main__.Y object at 0x7f287e7692d0>
```

Correct me if I am wrong. I do not think this answer is complete but these are complications I found worth motivating to not use `__init__` additionally to that the objects should be immutable as mentioned by  Martijn Pieters and user4815162342 [[source]](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__)

Waiting for 2 downvotes to delete the answer.

Comment: +1 - your previous answers were a bit... cryptic... but this one makes sense